# How to show timezone with hours and minutes with DateTimeFormatter?

Tags: java, kotlin

I need to get string of current time in format like this: `2019-12-24T09:20:35.8062135+03:00`

I can't understand what to do with timezone. My implementation:

```
yyyyMMdd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSX
```

It's without zeroes in the end. How can I do it correctly?

The code:

```
val FORMATTER: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSX")
println(ZonedDateTime.now().format(FORMATTER))
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html the one letter X will only output the hour offset only. Two Xs will output also the minutes but without colon separation. To get the minutes as well colon separation you should use 3 Xs:

```
val FORMATTER: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSXXX")
println(ZonedDateTime.now().format(FORMATTER))
```